# How to 'align' text in RichTextBox C#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, alignment

How do I align the text in a RichTextBox?

[image: RTB]

Basically, the RTB contains:

"--testing"

"--TESTING"

"TESTING--"

"testing--"

Which all have the same  number of characters, but have different alignments. How can I align them properly? Im fairly new to C# and confused since it aligned properly in Java's TextArea.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "aligning" in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to change the font to a monospaced font, like Courier.  This behavior you're showing is standard with most fonts, as not all characters are the same width.

Comment: I cant believe it was as simple as that. I tested other fonts but unluckily they weren't monospaced fonts and I just gave up. Thanks for that!

Comment: Simple, basic and brilliant.  So obvious yet I would never have thought it in a million years...

Answer (score 44):

You want to use the [RichTextBox.SelectionAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

For instance if you want the whole textbox centered, then you would do:

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

If you want only part of the textbox with a certain alignment, then use the RichTextBox.Select() routine to select the text, then set the SelectionAlignment property.

Comment: Is there any way I can define alignment of the text in moment when I append text in RichTextBox? Otherwise, I have to append text, and then find the text I've inserted, select it, and then change it's alignment.

Comment: SelectionAlignment doesn't exist in WPF : (

Comment: Yes. SelectionAlignment does not exist in WPF. How do we acheive the same functionality in WPF?

Answer (score 5):

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is very necessary for you to use a rich textbox, you can simply use a textbox and choose alignment as

```
textbox.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;/*could be left, right or center*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
RichTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

or

```cs
GetRichTextBox().SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

for multiple pages.