# Right and Left alignment richtextbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment, richtextbox

I wanna make a box where I can display certain text left oriented and certain text right oriented in C#.
For example,

**Code**

```
If (msg from admin)
   richTextBox.Append(rightAligned(msg))
else
   richTextBox.Append(leftAligned(msg))
```

I tried `SelectionAlignment` feature of `richTextBox`, but it applies particular format for all the text in the box. How can I achieve desired result? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be Better if you use Panel Instead of RichTExtBox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.Newline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RichTextBox.SelectionAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) for your richTextBox.

For Example:

```
if (msg from admin) {
    richTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + msg);
    richTextBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
} else {
    richTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + msg);
    richTextBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To just set the alignment of the *appended* text, you need to select just the appended text, then use the [`SelectionAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
    public static void AppendLineAndAlignText(this RichTextBox richTextBox, string text, HorizontalAlignment alignment)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return;
        var index = richTextBox.Lines.Length;                      // Get the initial number of lines.
        richTextBox.AppendText("\n" + text);                       // Append a newline, and the text (which might also contain newlines).
        var start = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(index);  // Get the 1st char index of the appended text
        var length = richTextBox.Text.Length;     
        richTextBox.Select(start, length - index);                 // Select from there to the end
        richTextBox.SelectionAlignment = alignment;                // Set the alignment of the selection.
        richTextBox.DeselectAll();
    }
```

After testing a bit, it seems that just setting the `SelectionAlignment` will work as long as the `text` string contains no newline characters, but if there are embedded newlines, only the last appended line gets aligned correctly.

```
    public static void AppendLineAndAlignText(this RichTextBox richTextBox, string text, HorizontalAlignment alignment)
    {
        // This only works if "text" contains no newline characters.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return;
        richTextBox.AppendText("\n" + text);                       // Append a newline, and the text (which must not also contain newlines).
        richTextBox.SelectionAlignment = alignment;                // Set the alignment of the selection.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This Could be done as well :)

```
 If (...)
    {
       textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
       textBox1.Text = " Blah Blah ";
    }
else
   {
       textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
       textBox1.Text = " Blah Blah Right";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [RichTextBox.SelectionAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Shamelessly stolen from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6243453/478049).

It appears you will have to append the text, select it and then change SelectionAlignment.